# Do I need to include all the pages of my website in the XML sitemap for SEO purposes?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

Is it necessary for SEO purposes to add all the listings of my website to the XML sitemap? And will a page that is added to the sitemap definitely be indexed in Google Webmaster?

I have a website where users post ads from external sources. Should those pages be marked as "noindex"? Or should I include their links in the sitemap?

Comment: See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox) which shows that Sitemaps have little influence on SEO.  They don't usually get pages indexed, and they don't help rankings.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your good question, it also may be others question.
Actually, [A sitemap tells Google which pages and files you think are important](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/overview#do-i-need-a-sitemap) in your site, and also provides valuable information about these files.
If your site's pages are properly linked, Google can usually discover most of your site.

Proper linking means that all pages that you deem important can be reached through some form of navigation, be that your site's menu or links that you placed on pages. Even so, a sitemap can improve the crawling of larger or more complex sites, or more specialized files.

A sitemap helps search engines discover URLs on your site, but it doesn't guarantee that all the items in your sitemap will be crawled and indexed. However, in most cases, your site will benefit from having a sitemap.

About second question:
If your site offers people to publish Ads, dont "noindex" their posts, But their links need to have this Attribute: `rel="nofollow", nofollow` tag does not let google crawlers leaving your website.

Comment: This is 95% a copy-paste of https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/overview. This was directly linked to in the original question, but for some reason the editor removed that attribution entirely.

Comment: My intention regarding the second question was that we are a marketplace and our users introduce their products on our website through seller panels. In other words, these contents are user-generated content (UGC).

Considering that the introduced products may have short and poor content, can we index these products or not? Can we also add the links of these products to the sitemap?

Comment: Actually, It depends on your strategy, anyway put your website url

Comment: https://anbarsang.ir

Answer (score 0):

Sitemap is only here to tell GoogleBot that hey, here are all of my pages on my website, and here are they located
specifying the categories.
Also sitemap doesn’t help in indexing directly. However, because sitemap  helps Google bot about your webpages locations, which can improves Indexing chances.
By the way, we usually create sitemap for entire website and specifying the categories, like pages, blog posts, landing pages and more.

in your case, you said there’s a user generated content where they post ads on your marketplace website,  there is no issue of creating or adding sitemap for these pages.
and about the indexing, it’s totally on Google.